# Why did Dumbledore reveal the prophecy to Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

At the end of the Harry Potter 5, Dumbledore shows the prophecy to Harry, whose mind is still connected to Voldemort's . Why? Wasn't protecting the prophecy his goal? Were Harry's and Voldemort's minds still connected?

Comment: Voldemort is now aware of the link and is blocking Harry out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is explained in the next book.

> “So tell me, Harry,” said Dumbledore. “Your scar... has it been hurting at all?”
>
> Harry raised a hand unconsciously to his forehead and rubbed the lightning-shaped mark.
>
> “No,” he said, “and I’ve been wondering about that. I thought it would be burning all the time now Voldemort’s getting so powerful again.”
>
> He glanced up at Dumbledore and saw that he was wearing a satisfied expression.
>
> “I, on the other hand, thought otherwise,” said Dumbledore. **“Lord Voldemort has finally realized the dangerous access to his thoughts and feelings you have been enjoying. It appears that he is now employing Occlumency against you.”**
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince Chapter 4, Horace Slughorn</sup></sub>

***Updated the answer.***

To read Harry's thoughts, Voldemort would have to enter his mind but he cannot/would not enter Harry's mind because he failed to possess Harry once (because of love). That would have hurt Voldemort's ego and he would not try to do it again.

> That power also saved you from possession by Voldemort, because he could not bear to reside in a body so full of the force he detests. In the end, it mattered not that you could not close your mind. It was your heart that saved you.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix Chapter 37, The Lost Prophecy</sup></sub>

Comment: But voldemort has previously used the connection to his advantage and he can send wrong messages and feeling he can also block stuff he needs so why would he block harry .

Comment: @kiyarash if Voldermort can use the connection, so can Harry Potter and Dumbledore.